# Wordpress Create a new Website

Tags: wordpress

I am newbie in Wordpress development. One of my client is asking to create a new project. My Clients' needs are:

Basically he wants to add contests for city wise. On the website entering page, a user sign up form would be there. If a user enters a zip code then according to zip code his/her city will be traced and this entry would be filled under this city. After signing up he/she could upload their videos on the server. There will be an another option to record audio/video online on the website. To record video on live contestant needs to pay little amount. Admin can create couple of logins for the CMS. These users can login and only see contestant's videos not their private information. These users can send video download link to anyone as they want. Admin also wants to run sweepstakes for cities.

Can I create this whole project in Wordpress ? If I could, then which plugins do I need to research more ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes you can do it, but this is not for newbies. And recommending you an approach between the countless options makes no sense and it's not the purpose of SO, please do your research first, and then get back with a real question if you need to

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. And off-topic since it's asking for libraries to use. Also your client hired YOU to do this for him, so you're getting paid and asking us to solve your problems for free? That's just rude man.

Comment: No Ewit it's not like that. I am going to make this website in cake PHP as I'd already been started to work on it. I just want to know some other available options with the wordpress.

Comment: Maybe my tone was a bit negative. I just hate questions where someone seems to be copying the requirements section and asking us: "can it be done". But Fabio's comment seems about right to answer it.

Comment: Thanks fabio for your time but will you please suggest some plugins ? I'm familiar with the core PHP and have been researching in wordpress for a days.